# Facebook returns ID but no post exists. iOS sharekit video upload

Tags: ios, facebook, video, sharekit

I'm uploading video to Facebook from my iOS app. It seems to upload correctly, but no post shows on my wall.

I read the the API documentation, and it said that in the case of a success it returns a video ID, which is exactly what is happening - it's just that the ID doesn't seem to point to anything and there's nothing on the user's profile.

Photo upload works fine, it's just the video that fails.

Note: this did work a few days ago, then I before I started compressing the videos to upload. I've tried to revert back to the non compressed video, but had no luck, they don't work now either.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks.